# Cowboys shooting at each other

Tags: probability

A and B participate in a duel(they shoot one against each other).There are 3 possibilities :

1.A shoots then B

2.B shoots then A

3.they both shoot at each other at the same time.

the events above - 1,2 and 3 have the same probability

if the probability of A to kill B is 0.7 and B to kill A is 0.6.What is the probability A to be murdered?

What I have tried:Let T be the event B kills A which means A is murdered.
Then P(T) = P(X) + P(Y) where P(X) is the probability B wins in a duel and they don't shoot at the same time and P(Y) is they shoot at each other and B wins .

For P(X) we have P(X) = 0.7 * 0.3 + 0.3 * 0.4 * P(X) where we can find P(X)

P(Y) should be 0.7 * 0.8.
since for P(X) we have 1/3 probability and for P(Y) also the answer should be

$\frac{1}{3}*P(X) + \frac{1}{3}*P(Y)$?

Comment: "the events above - 1,2 and 3 have the same probability" is in contradiction with the next sentence "if the probability of A to kill B is 0.7 and B to kill A is 0.6"...

Comment: the events 1,2,3 to happen have the same probability however A killing B and B killing A is different than 1,2 or 3 and their probability is 0.6 and 0.7 respectively

Comment: thanks, now I got it, sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider each case separately:

1. A shoots then B.

For A to be murdered, A has to miss first, then B has to shoot A. The probability of A missing is $1 - 0.7 = 0.3$, the probability of A missing, then B killing A is $0.3 \cdot 0.6 = 0.18$.

2. B shoots then A.

In this case, the probability of A dying is just $0.6$.

3. They both shoot at each other at the same time.

In this case the probability is also $0.6$, because events "A kills B" and "B kills A" are independent.

Finally, the probability of A being killed is $\frac13 \cdot 0.18 + \frac13 \cdot 0.6 + \frac13 \cdot 0.6 = 0.46$.

---

If you want to find the probability of A's death after indefinitely many rounds, you have to find probabilities that A dies during $n$-th round (for $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$) and then sum those probabilities up.

The probability that A dies during the first round is 0.46 (as we found earlier). The next round happens only if A and B survive. The probability of that is $0.3\cdot0.4 = 0.12$ (A and B both have to miss in all 3 cases). So the probability of A being killed during the second round is $0.12 \cdot 0.46$. For the third round it's $0.12^2 \cdot 0.46$ (because A and B have to survive two previous rounds). In general, we can see that the probability of A's death during the $n$-th round is $0.46\cdot(0.12)^{n-1}$. Now we sum up those probabilities.

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 0.46\cdot(0.12)^{n-1} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 0.46\cdot(0.12)^{n} = 0.46\cdot\sum_{n=0}^\infty(0.12)^{n} = 0.46 \cdot \frac{1}{1-0.12}  = 0.52\overline{27}$

(See [Geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series))

Comment: but after each case one can survive ( case 1 and 2) and both can survive (case 3 ) , shouldn't we take into consideration ?

Comment: Depends on which probability you are trying to find. In this case, we found the probability of A's death if everyone gets to fire one shot. If you want to find the probability of A's death after indefinitely many shots, then yes, you do have to account for who survives after each iteration. You need to find the probabilities $p_n$ of A dying after the $n$-th iteration, and then sum them up from $n=1$ to $\infty$.

Comment: yeah I am interested in finding that, can you show how it can be found?

Comment: Yes, see my updated answer.